# Schedule workflows via external tool

Tags: workflow, dynamics-crm-2011

I've been doing some research into scheduling workflows to run at certain times/dates but I haven't really found anything that does what I need to. I read somewhere that workflows can be created in CRM and then run by a console tool or something by a Windows schedule service. By what I've read it sounds like this would be what I need but I can't find anywhere that tells me how to create one of these or set it up, so I was wondering if anyone would be able to help me with it.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of options come to mind:

1. [Scribe Insight can trigger workflows](http://nicolagrillo.blogspot.com/2012/04/scribe-scribe-insight-to-trigger-crm.html)
2. Create an attribute on
   your entity that triggers your workflow.  Update the field via SSIS,
   Scribe or scheduled command-line application

Comment: Ah, I didn't realise that Scribe could be used to trigger workflows. We're already using that for data migration so that'll be very useful. Thanks