# How to transfer data from Sql Server 2008 R2 database to CRM 2011 internal database using Plugin?

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, dynamics-crm-2011

Scenario:
`X_source = N/A.

Y_source = SQL server 2008 R2.

Z_source = CRM 2011 database.`

I have a Y_source that will be updated daily with information from `X_source` at certain intervals. After that is done `Z_source` has to connect to the Y_source and upload that information. I have no control over X & Y source but do know that `Y_source` will be on the same network as the `Z_source`.

Problem:
Since I know that there are more than 200,000 records in `Y_source` I can't just call all the records and upload them to the `Z_source`. I have to find a way where I can iterate through them either in batches or 1 by 1. The idea I have in mind is to use T-SQL cursor's but this may seem like the wrong aprroach.

Sources:
I have the address and credentials to both Y & Z. I also have control over `Z_source`.

Edit
Ok let me clear some things out that I think may be important.:

1. `Z_source` is indeed a database that is separate from CRM 2011 but it is the origin of it's source.
2. Also the process that updates `Z_source` can be an external process from CRM 2011. Which means as long as the Database is updated it does not matter if CRM triggered the update or not.
3. The amount of Records to be handled will be well over 200,000.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution that I came up was to create a C# console application to connect to the `Y_source` retrieve the data then with the CRM 2011 SDK use the quickstart app in: Sdk/samplecode/cs/quickstart and modified it to insert in `Z_source`. This app will run via a Windows Task 6 hours after the `Y_source` gets updated so yeah I don't need a precise trigger for this.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you're used to SSIS but I think it could really help you !

Here's two nice posts about it : http://gotcrm.blogspot.be/2012/07/crm-2011-data-import-export-using-cozy.html and http://a33ik.blogspot.be/2012/02/integrating-crm-2011-using-sql.html

Regards,

Kévin

Comment: Thanks for your reply Kévin will look into your solution today, though it does seem like the same one that Peter mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

A few things:

1. Plugins in CRM 2011 are analogous to SQL triggers. CRM events, such as `Create`, `Delete`, `Update`, `Merge`, etc., *trigger* the execution of code you've written in a plugin. This doesn't seem appropriate for your situation as you want to do your operations in batches independently of CRM actions.
2. Nothing in CRM 2011 is done in set-based batches. Everything is done one database row at a time. (To prove this, profile any CRM event that you'd think should be done in one set and see the resultant SQL.) However, just because CRM 2011 can't use set based operations doesn't mean you have to gather all your source data in SQL Server one row at a time.

So I recommend the following:

- Write a quick app that pulls all the data from SQL Server at once. Call `.ToList()` on the result to place the result set in memory.
- Loop through the list of rows, and for each, do the appropriate action in CRM 2011 (`Create`, `Update`, `Delete`, etc.).

  - For each row, include the unique identifier of that row in the CRM record so you'll know in the future whether to delete or update the record when syncing with `Y-Source`.
- Schedule your app to be run whenever the `Y-Source` is updated.

Depending on your needs, the app can become a CLR stored procedure that is scheduled or triggered in SQL Server, a console app that's run on a schedule on a server, or anything else that can accomplish the above. The recent question [Schedule workflows via external tool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11723350/schedule-workflows-via-external-tool) speaks to this as well.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Peter. I will look into your solution today.